# Only can see ten items when I tried to grape website, but total is 40

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to web scraping using beautiful soup for the website (https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/bakery-bread/976759_1071964_976779). The class is "search-result-gridview-item-wrapper". Why I only can see 10 items inside, but total should be 40. I would like to grab all the items for my study.

I would like to grape all items from Walmart(https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/bakery-bread/976759_1071964_976779). I don't know how to grape all, because I use class =  search-result-gridview-item-wrapper", I only can see the first 10 items. Much appreciated!

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = "https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/bakery-bread/976759_1071964_976779"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()\
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") 
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "search-result-gridview-item-wrapper"})
len(containers)
10
```

I would like to grape all items- support needed!

Answer (score 2):

Grab it from the json script tag the page uses for content (`items` holds all the info. For example, `print(items[-1])` )

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/bakery-bread/976759_1071964_976779')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#searchContent').text)
items =  data['searchContent']['preso']['items']

for item in items:
    print(item['title'])
```